# How does a register based virtual machine work?

Tags: vm-implementation

How does a register based virtual machine work? 
I am looking for introduction to how a register based virtual machine works.
Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One example of a register-based VM with available source code is [Lua](http://www.lua.org/). There are a number of resources that might help...

- [The Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/doc/jucs05.pdf) From the authors of Lua itself.
- [LuLu](http://lulu.luaforge.net/) The Lua VM implemented in Lua, companion to a blog in Japanese.
- [A No Frills Intro to Lua 5.1 VM Instructions](http://luaforge.net/docman/view.php/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf) From a frequent contributor to the Lua community.